# GridView Command Button Not Firing When Validation Controls Are Embedded

Tags: asp.net, validation, datagridview

Why does the GridView's Command Buttons not fire properly when there are validation controls embedded in the ItemTemplate?
What is the point in allowing an EditItemTemplate if you can't even validate the user's input on the client side?!!!

The headache is not hard to reproduce, just create a simple GridView with at least one column that is an TemplateField.  Place a text box and a RequiredFieldValidator on the EditItemTemplate.

Does anyone have a workaround for this issue/problem/headache?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have ValidationGroup for the Buttons. please try something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" ValidationGroup='GridView1' CausesValidation='true' Text="Button" />
```

Comment: I tried that and it still doesn't work. The only way it works is to remove the validation controls. I'm seriously looking at the ListView as a replacement. In initial tests, the ListView does not break down with validators.

Comment: please make sure ValidationGroup='GridView1' name has similar name for both the Button and RequiredFieldValidator Control.

Comment: Tried that too. At this point I'm going with the ListView.  Thanks everyone for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to set ASPxTextBox ValidationGroup like this:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <dx:ASPxTextBox ValidationSettings-ValidationGroup='<%# Container.ValidationGroup %>' ../>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Look [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q390960.aspx) for detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However, your solution will only work for DevExpress controls. I tried running your binding expression on the Microsoft GridView and I got the following error:  'System.Web.UI.IDataItemContainer' does not contain a definition for 'ValidationGroup'

Comment: OK. Why is your question tagged with aspxgridview?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem.

when you want to put validation in certain column in gridview, you change that column to template. add your validator as usual, give it validationgroup name (as usual). then at the commandfield edit update column, convert that column also to template field, then set validationgroup name for "update" textlink.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem. QA reported the update command was not firing on a DatGrid we had set up for user settings.  Outside of the DataGrid, we happened to have two hidden input fields that were only visible when certain settings were in place.  However, I noticed in my testing that clicking update increased the overall height of the divs these fields were in; i.e. the validation controls for those fields were firing.

The issue definitely seems to be related to the ValidationGroup setting for the validation controls.

Wan's answer was somewhat helpful, however I did not have to convert the EditCommandColumn to a template field, and merely had to add the ValidationGroup attribute to it along with the Validation control in the EditItemTemplate. The sample below is based on the implementation that worked for me:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div runat="server" id="divConfirm">
            <div class="formfields float-off form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-4 text-right">
                    <p class="align-middle">Field 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="formfields float-off form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-4">
                    <input runat="server" id="confirm1" name="confirm1" />

                  <!-- this control was firing prior to adding the validation group -->
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="valConfirmReq" 
                      Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="confirm1"
                       ErrorMessage="*You must confirm etc. message">
                    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

     <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server" OnEditCommand="DataGrid_EditCommand" 
      OnCancelCommand="DataGrid1_CancelCommand"
      OnUpdateCommand="DataGrid1_UpdateCommand">
          <Columns>
              <asp:EditCommandColumn EditText="Edit" HeaderText="Edit"
               UpdateText="Update" CancelText="Cancel" ValidationGroup="DataGrid1">
              <%-- DataGrid code --%>
               <asp:TemplateColumn>
                   <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                       <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDDL" runat="server" 
                         ErrorMessage="*Please Select"
                         ValidationGroup="DataGrid1"
                         Display="Dynamic" 
                         ControlToValidate="ddl1" 
                         InitialValue="Select">
                       </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                   </EditItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateColumn>
           </Columns>
       </asp:DataGrid>
```